# Import the Windows system date into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, datetime, batch-file

I have been trying to create a batch file wherein I need to import the latest zip file date-time and size into a SQL Server 2012 table. I am able to reach to a point where Name, Size can be updated in SQL Server, but I am not able to handle the date.

The script:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *.zip /b /od /a-d') do set latest=%%a
echo Latest File: %latest%
call :setsize %latest%

:setsize
set FILESIZE=%~z1
set DATETIME=%~t1
echo %FILESIZE%
echo %DATETIME%
```

returns `06/27/2018 16:40` for date. I will be importing this into a SQL Server column of datatype `DateTime`. How do I use this in an `insert` statement?

Comment: Take a look at **sqlcmd** utility [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You miss a `goto :EOF` statement after `call`, so execution falls into `:setsize` afterwards again, unintentionally...